# What does "like" mean in this phrase?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, phrases

For example: "Like I’m gonna lose you"

Comment: It would normally be written "Like, I’m gonna lose you."  "Like", in this context, is an exclamation of sorts.  It is, like, the most distinguishing characteristic of [Valley](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Valley&utm_source=search-action).

Comment: It could be a phatic expression (but with a comma, as Hot Licks says) or it could mean "as if". More context is needed.

Answer (score 1):

This is a **conjunctive** use of ***like***, which means **as** or **as if**. Such usage of *like* is considered **informal** / **conversational**.

Comment: What you call the 'conjunctive' use of *like* to introduce a comparison is not 'informal'. But I suspect this is the discourse marker *like*, which is not a comparator but a focusing device and **is** informal.